# class path resource [classpath*:/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring

I have the following Folder Structure of my project:

[image]

I am using @PropertySource to load the property file 
When I am running the code I am getting property file not found

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abmt.*")
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }}
```

The property file is placed in resource folder. Please click on the link to view the folder structure.

Comment: try to put your file under `src/main/java` !

Comment: Wild guess, but try @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")

Comment: I tried putting the properties file in src/main/java I am getting the same Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.abmt.services.config.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: I tried @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") but its not working